# Aerospike data migration with no reason

Tags: monitoring, data-migration, key-value-store, aerospike

I have two Aerospike servers cluster runnning with a replication factor of 2. Both servers have the same replicated objects count, which means all records are replacated. But still the monitoring panel shows incoming and outgoing migration going on.

This happened after I restarted one of the servers. Now de I/O rate in both servers are above it was before restarting.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a node leaves the cluster, the partition id of any partition that node was a member of advances. When the node returns, they share their partition info with the cluster and migrations are required for any partition the returning node is a member of. This is done because while the node was down, the remaining node may have taken on writes.

For replication factor 2 with 2 nodes, both nodes are members of all partitions.

Comment: This happens even if there was no writes in the other node? Because during the node timeout, the other node did not have any write

Comment: Yes, when the cluster disruption happens, the partition IDs diverge. There are definitely ways rebalance could be made smarter here and they are being planned.